# How to read csv file from zip file on remote server with php?

Tags: php, csv, zip, sftp, fopen

I would like to read a zip file from a remote server. I currently have to following code :

```
    private $sftp;
    public function __construct($username, $password, $serverName)
    {
        $this->sftp = new Net_SFTP($serverName);
        if (!$this->sftp->login($username, $password)) {
            exit('Login Failed');
        }
    }

    public function buildRecords() {
        $sftp = $this->sftp;
        $sftp -> chdir(Constants::QUICKCHECK_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY);
        echo $sftp->pwd(); // show that we're in the 'test' directory
       // print_r($sftp->nlist());
        foreach($sftp->nlist() as $zipFile) {
            $handle = fopen("zip://" . $zipFile,'r');
            while($line = fgetcsv($handle)) {
                print_r($line);
            }
        }
    }
```

When I run this code and call these methods I get the error

```
Warning: fopen(zip://test.zip): failed to open stream: operation failed in /var/www/html/update_alerts2.php on line 67
```

How do I fix this error? (I'm using the phpseclib to sftp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fopen` will not magically be able to access files on a remote server only because you have logged into the server using phpseclib before.

You have to use phpseclib functions to retrieve the file contents.

Unfortunately phpseclib does not offer a way to read remote file contents by lines/chunks. But as it is CSV file, it is probably OK to load from file to memory at once. For that you can use [`SFTP::get`](https://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/documentation/net.html#net_sftp_get), if you do not specify the `$local_file` argument:

```
$contents = $sftp->get($zipFile);
$lines = explode("\n", $contents);
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    if (strlen($line) > 0)
    {
        $fields = str_getcsv($line);
        print_r($fields);
    }
}
```